# Do variables of interlocked functions have to declared as volatile in native C++

Tags: c++, volatile, interlocked

Is there a difference between :

```
    __declspec(align(8)) long long variable1; //assume shared among threads
    InterlockedIncrement64(&variable1);
```

And this:

```
    __declspec(align(8)) long long volatile variable2;//assume shared among threads
    InterlockedIncrement64(&variable2);
```

My guess would be that they operate exactly the same in this scenario. I think the only difference would be that if `variable1` is accessed without an interlocked function it is not guaranteed to be a current value while `variable2`is guaranteed to be a current value. Example:

```
long long x = variable1; //Not guaranteed to be the most recent value when accessed
long long y = variable2; //Guaranteed to be the most recent value when accessed
```

Am I correct in my assumptions? 
Note: I am using /volatile:ms compiler option in visual studio

Comment: The proper way would be `std::atomic<long long> variable1;` - http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic - rather than rely on MS/Windows specifics.

Comment: A bit of a complication in answering this is that `volatile` is threadsafe in MSVC++, which is not a portable assumption. But you already left portability behind with `InterlockedIncrement`